# Threading in Windows and Linux difference?

Tags: python, linux, windows, multithreading, difference

I had implement a chatroom in Linux written python It was multithreaded. Then moved code windows. Both the client and server run but after initial interaction do nothing. I think it's do the difference in how window and Linux handle thread can some confirm and explain how they work?

Comment: How are people supposed to answer this without you showing your code? Please add a [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No, this is more likely a bug in your program.